# SVG Animations with delay

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

## What?

I'm writing a React application where I have a sequential animation with delays using CSS. I'm animating the `<path />` elements in an SVG.

---

## The Problem

On mobiles *(less powerful than desktop devices)* the animation handles are attached *(it seems)* asynchronously. Thus, the animations are not guaranteed to be executed exactly as expected.

```
/* Elements.pcss file */ 

.element {
    opacity: 0.1;
    animation-duration: 1.7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.isAnimated {
    @for $i from 1 through $animatedItems {
        .element:nth-child($i) {
            animation-delay: calc(500ms - ($i * 100ms - 100ms)); /* <--- adding delay */
            animation-name: glow$i; /* <--- attaching animation */
        }
    }
}
```

---

## The Structure

The following is an abstraction of my code structure:

**Parent.tsx**

```
<Parent>
    <Elements /> {/* Renders all animating elements */}
</Parent>
```

**Elements.tsx**

```
import * as styles from "./Elements.pcss";

// ...

export class Elements extends React.PureComponent<{}, { isLoaded: boolean; }> {
    public state = {
        isLoaded: false,
    };

    public componentDidMount() {
        // The following is a hack to make it work. 
        // This is not a reliable solution. Thus, I want suggestions
        // from smarter people. 

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
            });
        }, 2000);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className={{ [styles.isAnimated]: this.state.isLoaded }}>
                <div className={styles.element} />
                <div className={styles.element} />
                <div className={styles.element} />
                <div className={styles.element} />
                <div className={styles.element} />
                <div className={styles.element} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

It should look somewhat like this. Smooth sequential animation. Instead sometimes some blocks start the animation at the same time, sometimes all animations start together, sometimes some other random combination happens.

[image]

- What would be the best way to implement this or solve such an issue?
- Has someone opted for mp4s and gifs instead of animating with CSS?

---

P.S. If something is unclear, I'll fix the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if anyone stumbles upon this and has a similar problem then the solution for me was completely different from the ones mentioned:

- I made the animation on canvas. This ensures smooth animation after any lag or user actions. https://jsbin.com/gijohucaxe/edit?js,output

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const cHeight = 249;
const cWidth = 72;
canvas.height = cHeight;
canvas.width = cWidth;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const bW = 72;
const bH = 48;


const fps = 120;
const duration = 1700;
const frameTime = 1000 / fps;
const elementCount = 6;

const startTime = Date.now();
let previousFrame = startTime;

const timings = {
  0: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.1],
  1: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1],
  2: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
  3: [0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
  4: [0.1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
  5: [1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
};

const timingFunction = (animationTime, animationLength, timing) => {

   // How many steps there are in timing definition, we count spaces not steps
  const positions = timing.length - 1;

  const stepSize = animationLength / positions; // How long time is for each step
  // For which step to take values

  const animationStep = Math.floor(animationTime / stepSize);
  // How much time is elapsed in step

  const minMaxTimingDelta = timing[animationStep + 1] - timing[animationStep];
  const timingAddition = timing[animationStep];

  const timeInStep = animationTime % stepSize;
  // Coificient to multiply max value with
  const coefficient = timeInStep / stepSize;
  const timingCoefficient = coefficient * minMaxTimingDelta;

  return timingAddition + timingCoefficient;
};


function drawElement(animationTime) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight)
  const min = 0;
  const max = 1;

  const delay = 700;
  const inDelay = animationTime < delay;
  const newAnimTime = duration - delay;

  for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
    const alpha = inDelay ? 0.1 : timingFunction(
      animationTime - delay,
      newAnimTime,
      timings[i],
      min,
      max,
    )


    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(0, i * (bH + 3), bW, bH);
    
  }
}


const animate = () => {
  if (Date.now() - previousFrame > frameTime) {
      previousFrame = Date.now();
      drawElement((previousFrame - startTime) % duration);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.1 {
  opacity: .9;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <canvas />
</body>
</html>
```

---

**N.B.** This approach was required only because of the specifics of the case. Here the issue was the mounting of the component with the animation as the app still loads. Meaning there were potentially some leftover JS processes going on that messed up DOM element mounting.

## Main takeaway is this:

Adding CSS animations with or without delays don't guarantee that all animations will initialise at the same time and thus be "synchronous".

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe combine this using one animation and one element.

Here is an idea:

```css
.box {
  height:250px;
  width:50px;
  background:
  /*Gradient that we will animate*/
  linear-gradient(to bottom,
    red 0px,red 30px,
    transparent 30px,transparent 50px,
    rgba(255,0,0,0.5) 50px, rgba(255,0,0,0.5) 80px,
    transparent 80px,transparent 100px,
    rgba(255,0,0,0.2) 100px, rgba(255,0,0,0.2) 0) 
    0 0/100% 130px no-repeat,
  /*Bottom gradient*/  
  repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      rgba(255,0,0,0.3) 0px,rgba(255,0,0,0.3) 30px,
      transparent 30px,transparent 50px); 
   animation:change 1s infinite steps(10);
}
@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-position:0 250px,0 0
  }
  to {
    background-position:0 -250px,0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: You meant as a mask?

Comment: Oh ok, I see, you didn’t mean a mask. Did you mean to start at the same time all animations but use different gradients?.

Comment: @RolandJegorov Yes I meant a complete different way to create the animation ;) ... the main idea is to have only one then there is plenty of ways to do. here I used gradient but it can be something else

Comment: But I have 6 elements. They are svg paths in the actual code. I don’t completely understand the one-element idea

Comment: @RolandJegorov you get rid of them :) ... My Idea is to completely change the code for something else .. as you can see my code produce the same visual output as the gif you added. So at the end we had the same result with different ways. and my idea rely on only one animation so you don't have the delay issue running many animations

Comment: I see. Only I can't get rid of these SVGs. They come from the designers. The result won't actually be an animated rectangle.

Comment: Maybe, I could try puttings these SVGs as backgrounds instead. Dunno, if this would work yet tho

Comment: @RolandJegorov yes you can have the SVG as background and you can have multiple background